# How can I remove this floor transition, and what should it be replaced with once I lay LVP?

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor

I'm planning to replace a linoleum floor with LVP.  The transition strip/threshold matches the wood floor, but since the LVP is a few mm thicker than the linoleum, I don't think it'll fit once I lay the new floor.

My questions are:

1. How do I remove this transition strip without damaging the wood, so I can get a better idea of what I'm working with?
2. Once the LVP is put down, what should I replace it with?  The only thing I can think of is to cut it back to the middle of the door jamb, and then add another low-profile threshold strip on top of it to cover the junction with the LVP.

[image: The Situation]

Answer (score 1):

Why remove it?  It's matched perfectly to the floor outside the room, and you have vinyl now so just slice the vinyl carefully where it meets the wood now, and if the new floor is a bit thicker it'll level up perfectly and look great.    If the new floor is higher than the wood floor add a narrow brass threshhold to protect its edge.

Comment: I was worried about being able to slice the LVP accurately enough to make the junction look good.  I guess I could practice on some scraps.  Although come to think of it, that'll be the edge of the vinyl anyway so maybe it'll be straight automatically.

Comment: Leave a small gap and caulk it for a smooth transition and room for movement

Comment: If you really screw it up ... same answer .... a narrow brass threshhold.  Everyone will just think you're being fancy.